# Carousel not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I read through the other questions and the answers don't seem to be working.  Next and previous buttons do not work in my bootstrap carousel.  Trip reorganizing the .js files and using different versions of jquery.  Nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span 12 pagination-centered">

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                   <!--Carousel Items-->
                               <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="active item"><img src="img/bfgn.png" height="300" width="300" alt="bfgn" /></div>
                                        <div class="item"><img src="img/ft.png" height="300" width="300" alt="ft" /></div>
                               </div>
                    <!--Carousel Nav-->
                               <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                               <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my js list at the end:

```
    <!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you look at the browser's console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your custom JS? If not,try removing this code:

```
     script src="js/bootstrap.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting a carousel, what tells it that it's a carousel, and not just a random `div` that you have sitting around?

You should add this *immediately* after the `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">`'s `</div>` (basically after the carousel code):

```
<script>
 $('.carousel').carousel();
</script>
```

Or, if your feeling a little creative, you can do something like:

```
<script>
 $('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 4000
 });
</script>
```

You can change the 4000ms to however long you wish to have each slide displayed.

I hope I appeared of assistance to you. If not, please let me know if I can help you in any other ways in the comments below.